# Is it possible to change the language in the EV3 Education software?

Tags: ev3, education

I have only 1 language in menu "Edit - Change language":

[image]

Is it possible to add another language packs to EV3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you have the Education version of the EV3 software. I would suggest checking with the LEGO Education support. It may be different from the retail version in this regard.

For the retail version:

From the [MINDSTORMS Support page](http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/support):

> 3.3 What languages are the LEGO® MINDSTORMS® EV3 Home Edition Software available in?
>
> You can download the EV3 Software for free from LEGO.com/mindstorms in the following languages:
>
> ```
> Chinese (Simplified)
> Danish
> Dutch
> US English
> French
> German
> Japanese
> Korean
> Russian
> Spanish (ESSA)
> ```

These are available via the respective download pages. For example, the US English version is downloaded at http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads/download-software. However, the installer is for the whole program. There are not "language packs" that contain just the languages.

To test, I installed the German version in addition to the English version and now I have two languages available on the Edit menu.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer and testing! When you installed the 2nd instance of retail EV3 - does it take the same amount of disk space as the 1st one? If so, it doesn't look quite efficiently.

Comment: No, it installed it in the same place on top of the existing install, so essentially, it just added another language. The other files are not duplicated.